# Will shared hosting work for my case?

Tags: hosting, vps, java, shared-hosting

I need to host a JSF application backed by a NoSQL database (Cassandra, which operates on a cluster of nodes). I'm going to purchase a set of  VPS to maintain the database server cluster. But to host the application should I consider purchasing a VPS or a shared hosting may work for intial stages(when user base is quite small). What is recommended for the initial stages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you start directly with a VPS or VPS stack for a few reasons:

- Control.
- You'll probably want or need to go there as your user base grows.
- They give you the opportunity to learn the supporting technologies for your application, rather than having them abstracted by the hosting provider and having to learn them later on when you're in a pinch for more performance, etc.
- You have no reliance on the hosting provider.

This is all on the basis that you have or can hire the right talent to get this all spun up yourself.  From your question, you didn't seem apprehensive about running this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. (I'm a bit new to this hosting arena/ managing servers), so please don't mind my stupidity & let me ask you that how do I decide whether I require a single VPS or a stack of multiple VPS.  Is a single VPS as web-server/app-server enough to start during initial phases ? (My application  offers a networking & socializing platform to a niche community of users)

Comment: @user, Jeff basically said this already but you can start on a single VPS with the application and database running side-by-side.  As you have a need, you can scale out.  There's a lot to learn in this area but it's worth investing your time to become an expert, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Use a VPS. Especially at point that you're backed by a *cluster* of data nodes, you'll find the pricing difference very cheap and you should have a much easier time scaling up.

Comment: Thanks. Is a single VPS as web-server/app-server enough to start during initial phases ? (My application offers a networking & socializing platform to a niche community of users) How do I decide about the no of VPS as app servers required?

Comment: @user Yes, it is enough to start. When you start running into issues, move to a more powerful VPS and eventually to load balancing.